# Javascript best practice to handle string array base 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to print a String of an Array, i receive an integer from Back-End, that can be only 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Which is the best way to print the correct String from my Array? I've thought two possible solutions.

```
var riskLevelMap = [ "", "low", "mediumLow", "medium", "high" ];
console.log(riskLevelMap[ integerValue ]);
```

Or

```
var riskLevelMap = [ "low", "mediumLow", "medium", "high" ];
console.log(riskLevelMap[ integerValue-1 ]);
```

Comment: Do what you think is better. It is personal opinion on style.

Comment: Not that it would cost much space but I'd take the second solution, just because you're not wasting one element and it's more "beatiful"

Comment: using second option is good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I would say go with the second option.

As awkward as it may seem, the additional empty string can be troublesome.

`[ "", "low", "mediumLow", "medium", "high" ];` technically takes up (marginally) more space. So, from a memory optimization standpoint, it is technically less desirable. It also isn't convention to have your used elements start at 1. So it could confuse you when writing code down the rode.

Granted, `[ "low", "mediumLow", "medium", "high" ];` also has disadvantages. An additional calculation is required to return the desired value. So, from a calculation optimization standpoint, it is technically less desirable.

Thankfully, both are only marginally better or worse than the other.

Because the first option "breaks convention", I would suggest the second option. It is more intuitive, and isn't inserting useless padding elements.